# Xamarin Windows Simulator : black screen

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, simulator

I wrote a Xamarin application, it runs fine with UWP but when I try to use the "simulator" (Windows Simulator), the Simulator windows appear but it keeps loading forever, even 30 minutes... nothing is happening!

I contacted MS, but no answer for now :-(

PS: I use VS 2017 !

Thanks